# What is the cokernel of this map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} -12 & 6 &0\\ 58 & 34 & 18 \\ 18 & 12 & 6\end{pmatrix}$$

The problem ask me to decompose the kernel and cokernel of this matrix (regarded as a linear map) into cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$ modules (abelian groups). I immediately found the one dimensional kernel, but I do not know how to deal with the cokernel. It should have dimension one as well, but it might be a direct sum of cyclic groups. Since this question appeared in all kinds of prelim tests I feel these must be a universal way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universal way to solve this kind of problem is provided by the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).